# Disable TemplaVoila Backend Layout for some sections

Tags: typo3, fluid, templavoila

I hope a TemplaVoila Professional can help me with this little challenge.

I've a TYPO3 6.2.6 Installation with TemplaVoila 1.9.2. We are now switching over to Fluid and I want to start with one section, a small microsite.

How can I disable TemplaVoila BE-Layout and enable the Fluid BE-Layout for this Tree? I already set "Enable the classic Page module" to true and set my Fluid BE-Layout in the Pagesettings, but it still gives me the "TemplaVoila-View".

Hope someone can help me with that.

Thank's alot!

Lufi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the classic Page module as you already did and clear the entire Cache as always. After that you see two "Page" Modules in the upper right corner of the t3 backend and can switch between "Classic" and TV-Mode.
Don't forget to create a new / clean template for your page tree. that's it. :- )

Answer (score 0):

I have used the extension which convert the templavoila to grid element + fluid.

I don't know the process that fully convert the site into the fluid.

But We can convert the templavoila site to fluid + gridelement.

Checkout this extension: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/sf_tv2fluidge

Please read the migration story here: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/sf_tv2fluidge/

Comment: Thank's, but I don't want to convert anything - i want to use both at the same time.